# SQL - Get multiple values when limit 1

Tags: php, html, sql

If I have a table like this:

```
ID | ident | product
 1 | cucu1 | 99867 |
 2 | kkju7 | 88987 |
 3 | sjdu4 | 66754 |
 4 | kjhu6 | 76654 |
 5 | cucu1 | 98876 |
```

And use this query: `SELECT ident,COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE status=? AND team=? AND DATE(date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY ident order by COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1`

I get the value: `cucu1`, since that has the most rows.

But if my table is like this:

```
ID | ident | product
 1 | cucu1 | 99867 |
 2 | kkju7 | 88987 |
 3 | sjdu4 | 66754 |
 4 | kkju7 | 76654 |
 5 | cucu1 | 98876 |
```

It should return both `cucu1` and `kkju7`, since they are the highest with same count, but still it gives me only `cucu1`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rank()`:

```
SELECT ident, cnt
FROM (SELECT ident, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sales
      WHERE status = ? AND team = ? AND
            DATE(date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      GROUP BY ident
     ) i
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me error `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in` and `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement `. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Catalus1 . . . This query is expecting two parameters, you should be passing them in.  This is part of the query in *your question* by the way.

Comment: **If this ISN'T a duplicate**, please do a better job of explaining the resolving technique so that this page can be used to educationally close future duplicates.  I trust that someone who answers so many sql questions and with more than a million points will know where to find a good duplicate to close this page with.

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` keyword simply limits the results to 1 row, no matter if there are equal values before or after the returned row.

A better solution would be to select the rows which have a count that's equal to max count in the query, which can be achieved by the following query:

```
SELECT ident,COUNT(*)
FROM sales
WHERE status=?
    AND team=?
    AND DATE(date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY ident
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(COUNT(*))
```